# Using SQL keywords with Yii

Tags: mysql, sql, naming, yii

I work with Yii 1.1.13.

Is it good to call a table `group`? (In MySQL GROUP is a keyword, as used in "GROUP BY")

Comment: Personally I would avoid naming tables/columns with MySQL reserved keywords since it will cause some errors if you forget to use backticks `\``.

Comment: It's both good and bad.  It's good because it's an accurate description of the data in that table.  It's bad because you have to do extra work every time you refer to it in a query.

Comment: you could use prefixed table names: `tbl_group`

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan suggestion is correct, but keep in mind that in Yii if you specify that you are using a prefixed table (`tbl_`), a model for the table `tbl_group` would still be referenced as `Group` (not `TblGroup`)

Comment: @eskimo: That's not true. Model class name can be whatever you want: `Group`, `TblGroup` or even `AwesomeGroupARModelForMyBestFriend`. It doesn't matter. Table linked to AR-model is to be defined in `tableName`-method. Also if you don't what to be tied on that prefix (it can be chaged in future) then: first - `tablePrefix` propery of `CDbConnection` class(`db` component in config) has to be equal to that prefix(e.g. `tbl_`), second - table name can be written in format `{{group}}`. After this "manipulations" you can refer to table via `{{group}}` in any sql-query

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bad idea, while some RDBMS support applying keywords to fields or tables (and accessing them using [] i.e select [group] from tbl ) it doesn't mean you should.
We recently have an issue where we had a field name group in one of our main tables, this was on a DB2 engine and we never had an issue, but then we moved  our DataWarehouse  to a  PostgreSQL's fork named Greenplum  and it didn't support a keyword as name for a field, so the DBA's were forced to change the field name in the migration and several services and reports failed until the code was changed. Production supported was impacted and everybody was mad/crazy about this.
It is my recommendation to avoid it,  and remember [anything that can go wrong, will go wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)